# jqGrid How to remove all rows without calling loadComplete

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to remove all the rows in the jqGrid, without calling jqgrid's loadComplete method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`clearGridData`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods). From the jqGrid documentation:

> Clears the currently loaded data from grid. If the clearfooter parameter is set to true, the method clears the data placed on the footer row.

A quick inspection of the code seems to confirm that this method does not call `loadComplete`, although it will call `gridComplete`.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the gridComplete method being called or some way I can determine and prevent some custom code in my gridComplete method being executed?

Comment: Well, you could use the same variable in both places. Set it to `false` initially, then change it to `true` before you call `clearGridData`. In `gridComplete` you can then use that variable to prevent your custom code from firing (and set it back to `false` in that case). Does that make sense?